# Compare Dates in 2 sheets vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 worksheets named "Control" and "Combined". In Control Sheet M5 = YYYY-MM-DD
In the combined sheet I have a column called SD where i have dates. I want to check if the date in Control M5 = All the dates in Combined SD Column (Ideally it should be) if not throw a msgbox saying date mismatch
I have the code but even though the dates match it still throws an error as mismatch
Also can anyone help me for the line in red please with 2 asterix

My code:

```vb
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Dim sDate, c as Range
    Dim bMatch as Boolean, sMsg as String

    Const START_ROW = 2
    sDate = Sheets("Control").Range("m5").Value
    For Each ws in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Control" Then
            bMatch = True
            With ws
                **For each c in .Range**
                    If not c.value = sDate Then
                        bMatch = False
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
                If bMatch Then
                    Call Macro9
                Else
                    smsg = "Date Mismatch"
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `column called SD` is it Column SD or the header cell has a string`SD`? `All the dates in Combined SD Column` does it start from row 1 or 2?

Comment: The column header is in row 1 called SD. All the dates start from row 2 pls

Comment: Do you need to dynamically locate col SD? If not (it means the location of the column is fixed), what's the column number of col SD?

Comment: Dynamically locate pls

Answer (score 0):

Please try.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sDate, c As Range, dateRng As Range
    Dim bMatch As Boolean, sMsg As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Const START_ROW = 2
    Const KEYCOL = "SD"
    sDate = Sheets("Control").Range("m5").Value
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Control" Then
            bMatch = True
            With ws
                ' Locate col SD
                Set c = .Rows(1).Find(KEYCOL, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
                If Not c Is Nothing Then
                    ' Get the last data row#
                    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, c.Column).End(xlUp).Row
                    ' Get the date range
                    Set dateRng = .Cells(START_ROW, c.Column).Resize(lastRow - START_ROW + 1)
                    ' Validate each date
                    For Each c In dateRng.Cells
                        If Not c.Value = sDate Then
                            bMatch = False
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                    If bMatch Then
                        Call Macro9
                    Else
                        sMsg = "Date Mismatch"
                    End If
                Else
                    MsgBox "Can't find column SD"
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```